# Why is SQL statement not working?

Tags: c#

I need to make this insert statement resilient to SQL injection.

I used params as per examples I researched but I get this error:"name Description does not exist in current context" in the following line of code: " sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", newDescription.Description);"
How can I fix this?

I also included a "test" string to prove that is resilient to the attack,passing the string and then checking in SQL Server that the database is safe. Is this the best way to test it?

```
Edit: Thanks to @Tibrogargan, who solved this issue.
```

Comment: Looks like newDescription is not declared anywhere.

Comment: What is the error? Is the code compiling?

Comment: @Tibrogargan Yes, you are right, what is the best way to declare it? And where in the code? Should I declare it before the SqlConnection conn? Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SQL. You've got nothing named `newDescription` in scope anywhere in the code you posted, so you can't use it in your parameter creation code. It's difficult to tell you where to declare it, because we don't know what it is or where it comes from. It's your code - don't you know?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, that is correct, I'm new to coding, what's the best way to include it?

Comment: @4201 What a can of worms.  Ok, so there is no way to tell what newDescription should be because AddWithValue infers it from the column in the database.  Since I have no idea what your database schema looks like I can't answer this.  I suspect you might want to replace `newDescription.Description` with `"This is a description"` or similar

Comment: Once again, *it's difficult to tell you what to do, because we don't know what it is or where it comes from*. I can't see your screen from where I'm sitting.

Comment: As an aside, your "SQL injection" does absolutely no injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Product
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                 "Data Source=localhost\\Win;Initial Catalog=Databasee; Integrated Security=True");

             string sql =
                 "INSERT INTO Products " +
                 "(Description)" +
                 "Values (@Description)";

             string toxin = "''); DELETE FROM Products; --";

             SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
             sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", toxin);
             conn.Open();
             sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
             conn.Close();
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: this is the solution! Works perfectly, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First is your newDescription.Description isn't declared that's why it displays an error

If you have a class called Description, this is how you instantiate the class:

```
Description newDescription = new Description();
```

And for your question on how you do an insert into using parameters here's how you do it.

You can do it like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Products (Description) Values (@Description)";
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = newDescription.SomePropertyInsideYourClass;
                    conn.Open();
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
```